# Excel formula calculation in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm having a bit of trouble with a calculation in Excel that needs to be written in C#.

The calculation in Excel is this:

```
=(26/1000*1,500+(0,0000039096*(26*26)+0,000082819*26+0,005066))*149468556,2
*(1+0,10%)
```

This gives the result of: `7310663,398`

In C# I have the exact same calculation (except for more decimals in the 14949.. number:

```
(26.0 / 1000.0 * 1.500 + (0.0000039096 * (26.0 * 26.0) + 0.000082819 * 26.0 + 0.005066)) * 149468556.2 * (1 + 0.1);
```

Which gives this result: `7632589.7787303319`

Since the last number in the formula is percent I've also tried this:

```
(26.0 / 1000.0 * 1.500 + (0.0000039096 * (26.0 * 26.0) + 0.000082819 * 26.0 + 0.005066)) * 149468556.2 * (1 + (0.1/100));
```

Which gives this result: `6945656.6986446008`

Of course, I need to match the Excel result in C#, but I'm totally stuck on how to achieve this. Guess I should've listened closer in the math lessons ;-)

Any help/input on this is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

All the best,

Bo

Comment: Why not break down the formula into something simpler and narrow down the issue? Excel's numbers behave differently than C# with regard to precision. Likely you're a victim of this.

Comment: Try changing `26 / 1000` to `26.0 / 1000.0` to perform double division instead of integer.

Comment: tenfour: I have tried, but I have to admit that I'm totally dumb when it comes to math :( Simply can't get the right result..

Comment: Is there a typo in  the excel formula? My version of Excel won't accept it as is..

Comment: Henrik: thanks a lot - that's actually the correct values in C#, just forgot to put it in my post :)

Comment: Jon: I just tried copying it in a new excel document, and it seems to work fine here? :)

Comment: It's because in the English locale, the number 1/10 is written as `0.1`, while in other locales (German, I think) it's written as `0,1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. In Excel, you used `(1+0,10%)` and in C# you used `(1 + 0.1)`.

Since `0.10%` is really `0.10 / 100`, you should use `(1 + 0.001)` instead.

So the correct C# would be:

```
(26.0 / 1000.0 * 1.500 + 
  (0.0000039096 * (26.0 * 26.0) + 0.000082819 * 26.0 + 0.005066)) * 
  149468556.2 * (1 + 0.001);
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to keep all the decimals. It's probably a precision mistake.

Your results are similar to what you should have which means it's not a calculation mistake (like forgetting to divide by 100, etc. Which would show directly in your result).

Answer (score 0):

Well atleast this gives me the result

```
double ds = (26.0 / 1000.0 * 1.500 + (0.0000039096 * (26.0 * 26.0) + 0.000082819 * 26.0 + 0.005066)) * 149468556.2 * (1.0 + 0.1/100.0);
Console.WriteLine(ds.ToString());
```

result `7310663.39550679`